# how to open very large SAS datasets, like "head" in Linux?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS, using SAS Enterprise Guide 8.3. I have very large datasets with .sas7bdat extension.

How can I open them to just see the first thousands rows? I don't need to process them, just view similar to a Linux "head".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the cool things about SAS is how performant Enterprise Guide and SAS Studio are with large datasets. Use the libraries tab in the left pane to open up a SAS dataset and scroll through it. I've done this on datasets that are nearly a billion rows long and it has no problem doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps if it is only to print you can do

```
proc print data=have(obs=10); run;
```

This will print the first 10 records

If you don't want the first 10 records you could specify `firstobs`

```
proc print data=have(firstobs=101 obs=110); run;
```

**Caution:** This will print 10 records starting at observation number 101, not 110 records starting at observation number 101!

If you want the actual subset in a table you can do it in a data step as well

```
data want;
set have(obs=110); 
run;

data want;
set have(firstobs=101 obs=110); 
run;
```